# Right Aligning Of ' # ' character in C

Tags: c, cs50

So I was doing my cs50 problem sets and i got stuck in the right aligning of the characters in my output.

The code for my program ( mario.c) is :

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int height=-1;

    while(height<0 || height>23)
    {
        scanf("%d",&height);
        printf("height: %d\n",height);
    }

    for(int i=1; i<=height; ++i)
    {
        for(int j=1;j<=i+1;++j)
        {
            printf("#");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Here is the output that i want:

[Output ( that i want )](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLBpH.png)

and the output that i am getting :

[Output ( that i am getting )](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lwpj.png)

Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Print the correct number of spaces first.

Comment: Instead of looping for correct amount of spaces and hashes you could experiment with the field width and precision specifiers, indicated by an asterisk. That might be out of scope for your assignment though.

Answer (score 1):

printf whitespace first.

```
for(int i = 1; i <= height; ++i)
{
    for (int k = 1; k <= height - i; ++k)
        printf(" ");
    for(int j = 1; j <= i + 1; ++j)
    {
        printf("#");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `sprintf` to get a string which contains the right amount of `#`s and then print it using an apropriate [`printf` format specifiers](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_printf.htm) like so:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= height; ++i)
{
  char *buf = malloc(i + 2);
  buf[i+1] = '\0';
  for (int j = 0; j < i + 1; j++)
  {
    sprintf(buf + j, "#"); // add a new # character after the last one
  }      
  printf("%*s\n", height + 1, buf);
  free(buf);
}
```

What happens? Let's have a look at the `printf` parameters.

```
"%*s"      // % means to start a placeholder
           // * tells this placeholder to reserve at least as many   
           //   characters as we tell it to via an variable
           // s tells printf that this is a placeholder for a string

height + 1 // reserver height + 1 character

buf        // stores the correct ammount of #
```

Answer (score 0):

Add width in your `printf` so you can print right align data.

```
for(int i=1;i<=height;++i)
{


    printf("%*c",(height + 1-i),'#');  //* to add width of size (height + 1-i)

    for( int j=1;j<=i;++j)
    {

        printf("#");

    }

    printf("\n");
}
```